# @babel/plugin-transform-runtime is allowing esm imports in cjs files

Tags: babeljs, rollupjs

I'm using Rollup.js, and babel to bundle my js library. I noticed that my dist cjs files are referencing esm core-js helpers in addition to the correct cjs helpers.

For instance, in my final cjs file, I see a reference to both `var _extends$2 = require('@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/esm/extends');` and `var _extends$3 = require('@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/extends');` when I run `yarn build:lib`.

Has anyone seen this before? Been racking my brain and haven't been able to find what is the cause of this.

For reference,
package.json (condensed for brevity)

```
{
    "name": "my-platform",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "dist/index.cjs",
    "module": "dist/my-platform.esm.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.18.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build:lib": "rollup -c",
        "build:docs": "build-storybook",
        "build": "concurrently \"yarn build:lib\" \"yarn build:docs\"",
    },
    "sideEffects": false,
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@emotion/core": "^10.0.22",
        "react": "^16.12.0 || 17"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "git-raw-commits": "2.0.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
        "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
        "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^10.0.23",
        "@emotion/core": "^10.0.22",
        "@jest/globals": "^26.6.2",
        "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.2",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^2.3.4",
    
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
        "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls": "^0.4.0",
        "babel-plugin-dev-expression": "^0.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.0.1",
        "concurrently": "^5.0.1",
        "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
        "husky": ">=4.3.8",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-emotion": "^10.0.26",
        "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.4.0",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
        "rollup": "^2.38.1",
        "rollup-plugin-delete": "^2.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.29.0",
        "stylelint": "^13.9.0",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
        "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
        "tslib": "^2.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "~7.12.18"
    }
}
```

babel.config

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    const isTest = api.env('test');
    api.cache.forever();
    return {
        presets: [
            [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                isTest ? { targets: { node: 'current' } } : { modules: false },
            ],
            '@babel/preset-react',
            '@babel/preset-typescript',
            '@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop',
        ],
        plugins: [
            'annotate-pure-calls',
            'dev-expression',
            'macros',
            [
                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                {
                    corejs: 3,
                    version: '^7.12.5',
                },
            ],
        ],
        comments: false,
    };
};
```

rollup.config.js

```
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import path from 'path';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import { DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS } from '@babel/core';
import pkg from './package.json';

const external = [
    ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {}),
    ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}),
];

const makeExternalPredicate = (externalArr) => {
    if (externalArr.length === 0) {
        return () => false;
    }
    const pattern = new RegExp(`^(${externalArr.join('|')})($|/)`);
    return (id) => pattern.test(id);
};

const configTerser = () =>
    terser({
        output: { comments: false },
        compress: {
            keep_infinity: true,
            pure_getters: true,
            passes: 10,
        },
        ecma: 5,
        toplevel: true,
        warnings: true,
    });

function writeCjsEntryFile() {
    const baseLine = `module.exports = require('./my-platform`;
    const contents = `
'use strict'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  ${baseLine}.cjs.production.min.js')
} else {
  ${baseLine}.cjs.development.js')
}
`;
    return fs.outputFile(path.join(__dirname, './dist', 'index.js'), contents);
}

const getEnv = (format, minify) => {
    switch (format) {
        case 'cjs':
            return minify ? 'production.' : 'development.';
        default:
            return '';
    }
};

const makeOutput = (format, minify) => ({
    file: `dist/my-platform.${format}.${getEnv(format, minify)}${
        minify ? 'min.' : ''
    }js`,
    esModule: true,
    exports: 'named',
    format,
    freeze: false,
    sourcemap: true,
    plugins: [
        minify && configTerser(),
        format === 'cjs' && {
            writeBundle: writeCjsEntryFile,
        },
    ],
});

let currentBundleIndex = 0;

const makeRollupConfig = (minify, format) => {
    return {
        input: './src/index.ts',
        output: makeOutput(format, minify),
        plugins: [
            currentBundleIndex === 1 && del({ targets: 'dist/**' }),
            minify &&
                replace({
                    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
                }),
            resolve({
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
            }),
            json(),
            typescript({
                typescript: require('typescript'),
                tsconfigOverride: {
                    exclude: [
                        '**/*.spec.ts',
                        '**/*.test.ts',
                        '**/*.stories.ts',
                        '**/*.spec.tsx',
                        '**/*.test.tsx',
                        '**/*.stories.tsx',
                        'node_modules',
                        'test',
                    ],
                    compilerOptions: {
                        target: 'esnext',
                        rootDir: 'src',
                    },
                },
            }),
            commonjs(),
            babel({
                babelHelpers: 'runtime',
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                extensions: [...DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS, '.ts', '.tsx'],
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        {
                            modules: false,
                        },
                    ],
                ],
                plugins: [
                    [
                        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                        {
                            useESModules: format === 'esm',
                            corejs: 3,
                            version: '^7.12.5',
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            }),
        ],
        external: makeExternalPredicate(external),
    };
};

export default [
    makeRollupConfig(false, 'cjs'),
    makeRollupConfig(false, 'esm'),
    makeRollupConfig(true, 'cjs'),
];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!